# Send an email after command has finished in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I have a command written on laravel which I wanna execute. It will take up at least 4 hours so I'd like to get an e-mail from the computer when the task is over. I'm using queues so I'd like to append the whole operation but I don't know if it's possible.

This is the current task:

```
public function handle()
    {

        $directory = 'pv';
        $files = Storage::allFiles($directory);
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $fname = basename($file);
            \Log::info('Procesando ',[$fname]);
            $arr = explode(" ", $fname);
            $day = substr($arr[2], 0, 10);
            $date = Carbon::parse($day);
            // this process goes to a queue in chunks
            Excel::queueImport(new POSImport($date), $file);
        }
    }
```

How do I append a new job that sends an e-mail after all is over? I'm not sure if I have to make a new command or a new job. I have the email job already tested and it works.

App\Jobs\SendMailFinished.php

```
public function handle()
    {
        //Sends message
        $me = 'me@example.com';
        $msg = 'Process finished';
        Mail::to($me)->queue(new TasksFinished($msg));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this a number of different ways.

#### Option 1

Send the mail at the end of your `handle` method. This is the least complicated option:

```
public function handle()
{

    // job logic...

    Mail::to($me)->queue(new TasksFinished($msg));
}
```

#### Option 2

Use [withChain](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-chaining) to chain the email job to be sent after the other job is successful:

```
YourTask::withChain([
    new SendMailFinished
])->dispatch();
```

#### Option 3

Add an event listener for `JobProcessed` to EventServiceProvider.php:

```
/**
 * Register any events for your application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        // $event->connectionName
        // $event->job
        // $event->job->payload()

        if ($was_my_job_class) {
            Mail::to($me)->queue(new TasksFinished($msg));
        }
    });
}
```

You can use [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815165/6038111) to determine if the processed job was the correct class.

Comment: If I put the e-mail task after the foreach will it work the way I want it?

Comment: @ffuentes I don't know how `Excel::queueImport` works so I can't answer that reliably. However, if your mail statement is reached at the end of `handle` (meaning no exceptions were thrown) then in most cases it should be safe to assume the job was successful